# ¿Como crear un Getter para una matriz en Java?

Tags: java

Quiero crear un Getter para un arreglo ya previamente creado para así poderlo llamar en cualquier momento, leí que era mas o menos así, implementando una copia del arreglo, pero no me ha funcionado.

```
public void llenarMatriz() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int estado_inicial[][] = new int[3][3];
    System.out.println("Ingrese datos de la matriz de 3x3");
    for (int h = 0; h < estado_inicial.length; h++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < estado_inicial.length; j++) {
            System.out.print("numeros[" + h + "][" + j + "]: ");
            estado_inicial[h][j] = sc.nextInt();
        }
    }

    sc.close();
    System.out.println("\nMatriz ForEach");
    for (int[] num : estado_inicial) {
        for (int elem : num) {
            System.out.print(elem + "\t"); // Tabulador
        }
        System.out.print("\n"); // Salto de Línea
    }
    estado_inicial = Arrays.copyOf(estado_inicial, estado_inicial.length);

}

/**
 * @return a copy of the array
 */
public int[] getArray() {
    return Arrays.copyOf(estado_inicial[][]);
}
```

Comment: ¿Un getter para una matriz? No entiendo lo que quieres hacer ni por qué, ¿podrías dar más detalles?

Answer (score 0):

Si deseas agregar el getter en la misma clase, define una variable de clase:

```
  private static int estado_inicial[][] = new int[3][3];
```

De esta forma cuando se ingresen los valores del array puedes obtenerlos mediante tu getter:

```
   public static int[][] getArray() {
      //return Arrays.copyOf(estado_inicial[][]);
      return estado_inicial;
    }
```

Este sería el código:

```
private static int estado_inicial[][] = new int[3][3];

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    //int estado_inicial[][] = new int[3][3];             
    System.out.println("Ingrese datos de la matriz de 3x3");
    for (int h = 0; h < estado_inicial.length; h++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < estado_inicial.length; j++) {
            System.out.print("numeros[" + h + "][" + j + "]: ");
            estado_inicial[h][j] = sc.nextInt();
        }
    }

    sc.close();
    System.out.println("\nMatriz ForEach");
    for (int[] num : estado_inicial) {
        for (int elem : num) {
            System.out.print(elem + "\t"); // Tabulador
        }
        System.out.print("\n"); // Salto de Línea
    }
    estado_inicial = Arrays.copyOf(estado_inicial, estado_inicial.length);

}


public static int[][] getArray() {
 // return Arrays.copyOf(estado_inicial[][]);
  return estado_inicial;
}
```